# Applying a backdrop-filter: blur(); to an SVG path

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to recreate an effect in CSS using an SVG. We have text saved as an SVG and needing to blur the backdrop behind the text only.

I know this is possible with block `<div>` elements by applying a css style of `backdrop-filter: blur(10px);`, but I am unable to get the same effect with SVG paths.

This is the desired effect
[image]

Here is a snippet of the SVG

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
   width="1040.474px" height="209.154px" viewBox="0 0 1040.474 209.154"
   enable-background="new 0 0 1040.474 209.154"
   xml:space="preserve">
      <g opacity="0.4">
         <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M6.336,27.021h78.367v6.485l-20.269,2.433l53.506,134.573l33.778-84.852l-20.267-49.721l-19.998-2.433
            v-6.485h78.365v6.485l-21.348,2.433l53.504,134.573l47.561-129.979l-23.781-7.026v-6.485h56.478v6.485l-20.538,7.298
            l-63.233,168.35h-16.213l-44.586-108.631l 43.236,108.631H98.212L27.145,35.939L6.336,33.507V27.021z"/>
      </g>
</svg>
```

How can you blur the backdrop behind the letters only?

Comment: The closest thing I can think of is the feGaussianBlur svg filter, see: https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_fegaussianblur.asp

Comment: @CesarCorrechel unfortunately that will blur the path(letter) and not the image behind it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

using `clipPath` SVG and clipping a duplicate img with the `blur` filter will get you something like this:

```css
body {
  margin 10px;
}

.clipped {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  clip-path: url(#svgTextPath);
  filter: blur(10px);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/99/500/300">
<img class="clipped" src="https://picsum.photos/id/99/500/300">

<svg height="0" width="0">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="svgTextPath">
            <text x="50" y="200" textLength="400px" font-family="Vollkorn" font-size="200px" font-weight="700"> Text </text>
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate/updated solution based on @matan-sanbira's solution using `backdrop-filter` instead of a duplicate image:

```css
body {
  margin 10px;
}

.relative {
  position: relative;
}

.clipped {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  clip-path: url(#svgTextPath);
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.25);
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="relative">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/99/500/300">
    <div class="clipped"></div>
</div>

<svg height="0" width="0">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="svgTextPath">
            <text x="50" y="200" textLength="400px" font-family="Vollkorn" font-size="200px" font-weight="700"> Text </text>
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
</svg>
```