# Apply background-filter with background-clip

Tags: css

I want to apply a blurred background effect to a text.
So I have this:

CSS

```
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
-webkit-background-clip: text;
color: transparent;
backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
```

HTML

```
<h3>this is a text</h3>`
```

However when backdrop-filter is applied that blur applied to the entire H3 container not just the clipped text. Why is that?

Comment: why not simply filter instead of backdrop-filter ?

Comment: That will blur the entire text, I want to blur the background inside of it. I think it's called "glassy text".

Comment: I think somehow similar to this `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039765/how-to-apply-a-css-filter-to-a-background-image`

Answer (score 0):

The backdrop is NOT the background. As example:

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
  background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1553532434-5ab5b6b84993?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1267&q=80) no-repeat 50% 50% /cover;
}

.test {
  width: 52px;
  height: 52px;
  background: url(https://img.icons8.com/material/24/ffffff/home--v5.png) no-repeat 50% 50%;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  
  backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Here you can see what `backdrop-filter` is applied **only to backdrop** of `.test` (underlying elements). **It is not applying to background** (you can see what house icon created with `background` stayed unblurred)

So, when you are attempting to use `background-clip` it clips only background (which is transparent). Backdrop is left as-is.

---

If you want glassy text you could look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60141217/applying-a-backdrop-filter-blur-to-an-svg-path).

*Home icon by Icons8*

Comment: Worth noting that `backdrop-filter` is [not enabled by default yet in Firefox](https://caniuse.com/css-backdrop-filter)

Comment: Using SVG for text is not an option for me.