# How can I blur the background behind text in CSS?

Tags: html, css, blur

I'm trying to create a simple little frontend project, and I need to make some text discernible from a background image.

How can I make the background behind the text blur? It's just blurring the container, I'd like to only blur behind the actual text.

My current code for this text:

```css
.center h1 {
    font-size: 100px;
    font-style: italic;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg,rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25));
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
}

/* added by editor for deomnstration purpose */
body {
  background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5b/St_Mary%27s_Church%2C_Castle_Street_1.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}
.center {
  position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
    text-align: center;
    width: max-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
<h1>GLUSH</h1>

<!-- Added by original poster for better running -->
</div>
```

This is just ending up like this:

[image: Image of bad-clipped blur on text.]

Is there any way to do this? I was working with `background-clip` earlier...

Comment: what have you tried so far? what is not working so far? have you tried `backdrop-filter: blur(1);`

Comment: As @tacoshy said, please add [code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question when asking questions on SO or the community will likely down vote your question and you will not get a favorable outcome.

Comment: Please add HTML and CSS to your question, thanks.

Comment: @tacoshy I've tried the `backdrop-filter:` method, and that's the only one i've found on the internet. I've showed how it doesn't work. As I can't find anything else on this, that's the only thing I've currently tried.

Answer (score 6):

Just use `backdrop-filter` and play with the `blur` and `saturate` filter to your liking. `blur` obviosly blurring the background while `saturate` givin it more "color depth"

```css
h1 {
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px) saturate(70%);
}

/* to make the header only as wide as the content and centering it */

h1 {
  width: min-content;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
  


/* added by editor for deomnstration purpose */

body {
  background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5b/St_Mary%27s_Church%2C_Castle_Street_1.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 5em;
}
```

```html
<h1>GLUSH</h1>
```

Comment: Hi, this isn't really answering my question. I can clarify it, but I'm actually asking how I can make the background blur only behind the text, not the container.

Comment: what is the difference? Why not just apply it to the entire container and make the container only as large as needed? Why overcomplicating this case?

Comment: I'm sorry, I think this is irrelevant now since I just edited my UI to accommodate. But just to clear things up, I was asking how to make the blur apply to the text so you don't have an ugly box of blur, only one under the text.

Comment: oh you mean the text itself not the background of the text

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to achieve the desired effect by utilising the `[blur]` value of the `text-shadow` property:

```
some-element {
  text-shadow: [x-offset] [y-offset] [blur] [color];
}
```

In my case, I have white text over a sandy background image, which was difficult to read due to the lack of contrast.

So, by using zero offets, and a generous blur value with a dark shadow, I was able to get a nice effect using:

```
my-element {
  text-shadow: 0 0 0.15em #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a SVG clipPath to blur only part of an image behind text, as explained there : [Applying a backdrop-filter: blur(); to an SVG path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60146437/10404482)

```css
body {
  margin 10px;
}

.relative {
  position: relative;
}

.clipped {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  clip-path: url(#svgTextPath);
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.25);
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="relative">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/99/500/300">
    <div class="clipped"></div>
</div>

<svg height="0" width="0">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="svgTextPath">
            <text x="50" y="200" textLength="400px" font-family="Vollkorn" font-size="200px" font-weight="700"> Text </text>
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
</svg>
```